# Hall Effect Sensor Wiring for Crankshaft Position Sensor

Tags: hall-effect

Please forgive my ignorance in my description. I have looked around and been unable to find what the following symbols mean: on wire number 51 there is a black filled circle with a dashed circle encompassing wires 1868 and 1869 going to the hall effect sensor. What does this mean? Also, what does the "sideways Z" symbol across those wires mean?

[Electrical Schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0xeo.png)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: Shielded twist pair with shld connected to the dot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure that the symbol means that the position sensor low and high lines are shielded (probably) twisted pairs, the shield being the grounded wire number 51.